# salt cmd.run minion didn't return

Tags: 7zip, salt-stack

In my salt state i am executing a local 7zip process to extract a archive. This process takes a while and uses 100% cpu. All other statements in my state are being executed normally but then the 7zip process starts the minion itself returns no response:

```
mymaster:/srv/salt/patch/abc# salt 'MYMINION' state.apply patch.abc.mystate_core_servers
MYMINION:
  Minion did not return. [No response]
```

The weird part is that this works from time to time. Any idea?

Comment: could you post the content of this sls file? have you tried to test it state by state to see which part raising this issue ?

Comment: first of all that could be tested pretty easy. execute a cmd.run in the state against the minion that consumes all the cpu. after a while the connection drops.

Comment: workaround: increase the priority of the salt process before executing such a high consuming process. that keeps the connection alive

Comment: We can't exactly help you if you don't provide the state file so that we could replicate this issue or see what your state is doing.

Comment: @gtmanfred: Will try to write a small example state file

Comment: To answer the question: We had a process with higher priority which consumes all the resources. Windows showed 100% usage for the 7zip process but that wasn't true